# Rails API with Devise - Unauthorized after successfull login

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a mobile app for IOS, Android and WP8, done in pure HTML/JS/CSS with JQuery Mobile - porting with Phonegap.

The API is done in rails with Devise as authentication - login is working fine - so far.

But when I add:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

To a controller - login and try to reach ex. the show action of a controller with a AJAX call from my mobile app, I get a "401 - unauthorized".

```
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:21.005537 #31339]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for     XX.XX.XX.XXX at 2013-11-27 22:50:21 +0100
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:21.008487 #31339]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:21.008632 #31339]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"remote"=>"true", "commit"=>"Sign in", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"1", "password"=>"XXXXXX", "email"=>"scrambled@gmail.com"}}
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:21.329300 #31339]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 320ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:26.915657 #31339]  INFO -- : Started GET "/investors/scrambled@gmail.com?callback=jQuery11020019103835336863995_1385589039514" for XX.XX.XX.XXX at 2013-11-27 22:50:26 +0100
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:26.917239 #31339]  INFO -- : Processing by InvestorsController#show as */*
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:26.917333 #31339]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"callback"=>"jQuery11020019103835336863995_1385589039514", "id"=>"scrambled@gmail.com"}
I, [2013-11-27T22:50:26.918942 #31339]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
F, [2013-11-27T22:50:26.934853 #31339] FATAL -- :
```

When I login, in my mobile app, the email logged in with is saved in Local Storage, and retrieved in investor.js to get the investor connected to that user - no probs with that.

### Rails API:

sessions_controller.rb

https://gist.github.com/Znow/cb86188e682570cc3958#file-sessions_controller-rb

investors_controller.rb

https://gist.github.com/Znow/cb86188e682570cc3958#file-investors_controller-rb

### Mobile App:

login.js

same gist as above

investor.js

same gist as above

If more files are needed, let me know, then I will update my gist.

Apparently I cant post more than 2 links because of that reputation stuff.

I really hope to sort this problem out quick, since I only need authenticated users to see certain stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

### EDIT:

I found the error.

I didnt have my controllers in a devise_scope block, so they didnt inherit the authentication stuff.

```
Api::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' } #:registrations => 'registrations',

  devise_scope :users do
    resources :investors, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy], :id => /.*/ do
      resources :deposits, except: [:new, :edit]    
    end

    resources :stocks, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources :reports, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources :events, except: [:new, :edit]
  end

  resources :news, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]

end
```

The thread can be closed